# How to add Bootstrap to Angular JS project?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use `Angular 2 Boilerplate`. Now I have the standart structure app with app.component.js.I tried to add Bootstrap CSS file in index.html.
It works.

But how can I add bootstrap styles in app otherwise?

Comment: using `angular-cli` or `systemjs`

Comment: This might help if you want angular 2 wrappers: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/